# CURL code in Python

Tags: python, curl

How can I convert this curl code to python code?

```
curl "https://api.havenondemand.com/1/api/sync/gettextstatistics/v1?url=http%3A%2F%2Fadelaide.backpage.com%2FPetsForSale%2Fcute-english-bulldog-pups-for-adoption%2F19942431&apikey=mykey"

curl -X POST --form "url=http://adelaide.backpage.com/PetsForSale/cute-english-bulldog-pups-for-adoption/19942431" --form "apikey=mykey" https://api.havenondemand.com/1/api/sync/gettextstatistics/v1
```

Comment: As a starting point, look into the `requests` library.

Comment: [cURL as DSL](https://shibukawa.github.io/curl_as_dsl/index.html) is a pretty fancy service that can convert curl command lines into language specific code, including python!

Answer (score 1):

First can be even

```
import requests

r = requests.get("https://api.havenondemand.com/1/api/sync/gettextstatistics/v1?url=http%3A%2F%2Fadelaide.backpage.com%2FPetsForSale%2Fcute-english-bulldog-pups-for-adoption%2F19942431&apikey=mykey")

print(r.text)
open("output.txt", "wb").write(r.content)
```

but more usefull can be

```
import requests

url = "https://api.havenondemand.com/1/api/sync/gettextstatistics/v1"                

payload = {
    "url": "http://adelaide.backpage.com/PetsForSale/cute-english-bulldog-pups-for-adoption/19942431",
    "apikey": "mykey",
}

r = requests.get(url, params=payload)

print(r.text)
open("output.txt", "wb").write(r.content)
```

Similar second

```
import requests

url = "https://api.havenondemand.com/1/api/sync/gettextstatistics/v1"                

payload = {
    "url": "http://adelaide.backpage.com/PetsForSale/cute-english-bulldog-pups-for-adoption/19942431",
    "apikey": "mykey",
}

r = requests.post(url, data=payload)

print(r.text)
open("output.txt", "wb").write(r.content)
```

`get()` uses `params=`, `post()` uses `data=` but some APIs may expect both `params=` and `data=` in `get()` or `post()`.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to use python `requests` module if you can get extra packages installed on your system.

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/